# car insurance claim, police report, minor damage and carfax

Tags: insurance, car-insurance

I parked my brand-new car on the street at night and woke up next morning to find out that someone, perhaps on the bike has hit it and the side mirror cover is off. The small dent on the side of the car at the door edge is almost invisible and the mirror cover can be replaced at a cost much less than the deductible for my insurance. On some friend's advice, I had reported this to the police. Let's say I don't take the insurance claim. Will the police report still show up as 'accidents reported' on my carfax report? I am just concerned that if it is an 'accident reported' in the carfax report, then I will lose a lot on the resale value of the car because of this minor incident.

Comment: And your insurance does not cover the loss in value? Is this an american spcialty - because my german and polish insurances do cover loss in value due to accidents.

Comment: They said they won't cover the loss in value (the so-called Diminished value claim) because they don't know the other party that is involved in this incident.

Comment: My understanding is that diminished value coverage varies by state. Some states only pay diminished value to third-parties under liability coverage, as the OP has discovered. Some states do include it under normal vehicle coverage. An issue too is you have to show a material decrease in value. A car normally gets small dents and scrapes as "wear and tear".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person is asking about the inner workings of a private company.

Comment: @PeteB. Since the Carfax report can affect the value of the car, I would say that this is on-topic.  Credit bureaus and banks are also private companies, but we accept questions on their policies.

Comment: @PeteB. to be precise, my question is whether the police report will be put on the carfax report as an 'Accident'. Or does the record of accident on carfax report depend on whether I use the insurance claim or not? In fact, it was the comments that were addressing the inner workings of my insurance company